# I want to make this posteri a4 paper size, how do I do it?

Tags: templates, conversion, paper-size, tikzposter, sciposter

```
\documentclass{a0poster}

\usepackage{fancytikzposter} 
\usetemplate{4}

\setblockspacing{3}
\setcolumnnumber{2}


\usepackage[margin=\margin cm, paperwidth=59.4cm, paperheight=84.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage[math]{kurier}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}



\setheaddrawingheight{11}


\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{.15 in}
 \addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-.875in}
 \addtolength{\textwidth}{1.75in}

 \addtolength{\topmargin}{-.875in}
 \addtolength{\textheight}{1.in}


\title{Globalization of Islamic Finance\\}

\author{Anna Shabalova\\ Bath Spa University}

\begin{document}
\ClearShipoutPicture
\AddToShipoutPicture{\BackgroundPicture}

\noindent 
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \initializesizeandshifts

  \ifthenelse{\equal{\template}{3}}{ 
    \titleblock{50}{1.4}
  }{
    \titleblock{50}{1.4}
  }


  \blocknode
  {Introduction}
  {\coloredbox{colorthree!50!}{
      \small
Islamic finance was developed four decades ago. It follows the Quran and the teachings of Prophet Muhammad and is often referred to as interest free finance. Islamic finance is based on five principles: ban on interest; ban on uncertainty and speculation; ban on financing certain economic sectors, risk sharing; and asset-backing principle. The more developed a system is the more likely it is to expand and so globalize. This research looked at determinants that affect globalization: quantitative development, awareness, governance and knowledge, help me answer my research question: \textit{\textbf{How globalized is Islamic Finance Industry when looking at development?}} The main reason for choosing this topic was to learn more about a new financial  niche as well as educate others. With more people choosing to behave ethically, Islamic finance can be beneficial as an ethical way to invest.  }}


     \blocknode
  {Results}
  {\coloredbox{colorthree!50!}{
      \small
      Islamic finance is present in 82 countries, 57 are Muslim majority and 25 are non-Muslim:
        \includegraphics[scale=0.645]{map}
        {\bf Financial institutions} (Islamic Banks, Takaful, Other Financial Institutions, Sukuk, and Islamic funds): Australia, Canada, Germany, France, Luxembourg, Singapore, South Africa, Switzerland, Thailand and United States.\\
         {\bf Awareness} (News, Conferences, Seminars): Australia, Djibouti, Maldives, Mauritania, Oman, Turkey, Uganda and United Kingdom.\\
          {\bf Governance } (Regulation, Shariah Governance and Corporate Governance): Australia, Oman, South Africa, Sri Lanka and United Kingdom.\\
           {\bf Knowledge}  (Educational courses, Research 2010-2012): Australia, France, India, Maldives, Oman, Sri Lanka, United Kingdom and United States.\\  }}


     \blocknode
  {Method}
  {\coloredbox{colorthree!50!}{
      \small
      To achieve an understanding of expansion of Islamic finance these methods were used:
     \begin{itemize}
         \item A development report on Islamic Finance to understand the widespread and levels of development
          \item An online questionnaire with two employees of Islamic Banks to gain an understanding within the industry
            \end{itemize}
From the information that was gained from the report all non-Muslim countries and other unusual performers were identified and reported. Later on the information from the questionnaire was used to enhance secondary data analysis. Primary research was carried out online because of the ability for wide and easy reach to interviewees. }}

  \startsecondcolumn 

 \blocknode
  {Discussion}
  {\coloredbox{colorthree!50!}{
      \small

{\bf Financial institutions} are very concentrated with top ten countries representing 95\% of assets in each sub-sector and Islamic banking is the most developed globally. Islamic funds are the most developed sub-sector in non-Muslim countries. The interview participants have said that the industry is lacking complex financial products. {\bf Awareness} is very balanced between countries, the news sector especially. Small countries have performed well such as Maldives. African countries and new to the sector countries have done a lot to promote Islamic finance. One participant noticed that there has been a change in demographics to younger population. There is a strong correlation between {\bf governance} and level of overall development. One of the participants said that the products that are offered are not always fully Shariah compliant. Development of {\bf knowledge} is very concentrated, but it has developed around the world and not only in Muslim countries. Malaysia and United Kingdom are leaders in this section. Participants have said that there is a lack of research in the area as well as in the breadth of topics covered.  }} 
 \blocknode
  {Reflection}
  {\coloredbox{colorthree!51!}{
      \small
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Investigating a new industry is very difficult because there is not a lot of published research 
     \item Gaining primary research in the finance industry is difficult because the information is sensitive, which limits the questions that can be asked
      \item  Time management is very important making a schedule with extra time would have been useful
       \item Reading during the summer helps to get a basic understanding and interest in the topic before wasting too much time
        \item Before writing a paper and choosing the research question it was helpful to research the industry and see whether there is enough research on the topic
         \item When choosing the topic it is helpful to have a tangible research question that can be answered 


    \end{itemize}

\hspace*{\fill}   }} 

         \blocknode
  {Further research}
  {\coloredbox{colorthree!51!}{
      \small
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Legal regulations and Governance in Islamic finance see what countries have done to promote Islamic finance
     \item Islamic finance has benefits not only for Muslims and it can be regarded as a new way to invest ethically
    \item Research on Islamic finance to see whether in the future it might converge or diverge from conventional finance
       \item Research how Shariah compliant is Islamic finance
    \end{itemize}

\hspace*{\fill}  }} 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you have a look at: http://texcatalogue.ctan.org/bytopic.html#classes and at http://texcatalogue.ctan.org/entries/a0poster.html (download documentation and search for posterdraft)

Answer (score 2):

The most simple general answer (wprks for any document) is provuded by the `pgfpages` package (and not `pdfpages`, even thouth very convenient for other task.).

Simply add in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
```

This package can also be used to make any kind for *nup with something like:

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm,landscape]
```

very useful for presentations.

Comment: Dear Jhor, You are very kind and helpful. Your answer has solved my problem. thank you very much for your helps.

Comment: It does not work with `tikzposter`?